# Minimize window from usercontrol in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to minimize my window , when I open other window/

This is a method in my user control which is in another user control, which is in another user control too.

```
WindowUploadFiles windowUploadFiles=new WindowUploadFiles();
//Minimize() - how to ?
            windowUploadFiles.ShowDialog();
// Maximize() - how to ?
```

Has anybody experience with this problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `WindowState` property to minimize/maximize/restore the window:

```
// Find the window that contains the control
Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);

// Minimize
window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

// Restore
window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```